# Step signal for ADC

Tags: adc

IEEE std1241-2010 specification part 6.2.1 test method part refer to "random walk" in the 3rd paragrah.

> Instead of a simple alternation about the desired code value, there will be a random walk about the transition level. The properties of this random walk depend on the relative values of the noise, the step size, and the code width.

What is the meaning of "random walk" for ADCs?

Comment: "Random walk" definition is possibly this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk

Comment: Yes, that is the mathematical definition. The relevant point for EE is that a random walk is what you get when you integrate noise. I'd need to see more context for the quote, but this may be referring to the result of the integration that is inherent in a [delta-sigma modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation).